# Interpreting and reading JSON with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm having trouble trying to make sense of this JSON string.

```
{
    "results":[
        {
            "user":{
                "gender":"female",
                "name":{
                    "title":"miss",
                    "first":"taylor",
                    "last":"anderson"
                },
                "location":{
                    "street":"3645 dogwood ave",
                    "city":"roseburg",
                    "state":"new hampshire",
                    "zip":"20963"
                },
                "email":"taylor.anderson49@example.com",
                "username":"heavyduck595",
                "password":"liverpool",
                "salt":"UK`o;9a_",
                "md5":"6c8db0305b4591d8d9820d9f8edfd162",
                "sha1":"906df4c09f3a87899666cb57bf974bd9b1950ea6",
                "sha256":"3b12f5e51688578f845bef8ae1750d3e263c2010691010a80ce632a6b2323c03",
                "registered":"1359027425",
                "dob":"16243995",
                "phone":"(934)-888-7068",
                "cell":"(727)-467-8384",
                "SSN":"697-20-6143",
                "picture":"http://api.randomuser.me/0.3/portraits/women/30.jpg"
            },
            "seed":"5eaf02877746c7e",
            "version":"0.3"
        }
    ]
}
```

It's the first time I've really used JSON and want to try and interpret it appropriately. This is the code i have thus far:

```
static class Results{
            String results;
        }

        static class User{
            String gender;
            String name;
            String location;
            List<Results> items;
        }


        private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int read;
                char[] chars = new char[1024];
                while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                    buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

                return buffer.toString();
            } finally {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            }
        }

        public void larry() throws Exception{
            String json = readUrl("http://api.randomuser.me/");
            System.out.println(json);
            Gson gson = new Gson();        
            User page = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);

            System.out.println(page.name);
            for (Results item : page.items)
              System.out.println("    " + item.results);
        }
```

Comment: Something else for printing indent you can use "\t" for tabulator instead of multiple white spaces like "    ".

Comment: Before you do anything else, go to json.org and spend the 5 minutes it takes to learn the JSON syntax -- it's very simple and easy to understand.  Then, before using something like GSON to directly produce custom Java objects, use one of the "clean" JSON parsers to parse the JSON into Maps and Lists and learn your way around those.  Then the complexities of GSON et al will be much easier to understand.

Comment: (And Google for "JSON online parser" -- there are several online tools that will syntax-check and format a JSON string, to make it easier to read.)

Comment: @Hot Licks thank you! that will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly complicated about JSON, or mapping it to your own Java classes. You just have to understand the basic structure.

Your JSON is an object that has exactly one field; `results`. This is what `{}` means:

```
{ "results": ... }
```

That field holds an array. That's the `[]`.

```
{ "results": [ ... ] }
```

That array holds another object (presumably you'd have more than one in an array, but the JSON you've posted just has one). That object has three fields, one of which ("user") holds another object with the other two being strings.

To map that to your own classes, you simply make them look like that JSON:

```
class JsonResult {
    List<Result> results; // JSON arrays map to Java Lists
}

class Result {
     User user;
     String seed;
     String version;
}

class User {
    String gender;
    Name name;
    // and so on ...
}

class Name {
    String title;
    String first;
    String last;
}
```

And so forth. You build classes to match the objects (again, denoted by `{}`) in the JSON, and structure everything accordingly.

As @HotLicks notes in his comment, you can decide not to map to Java classes and use a "clean" parser. In fact, Gson offers this with it's [`JsonParser`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) class. This will just parse the JSON to a tree from which you can extract the info you want:

```
JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(yourJsonString);
```

From there you can access the JSON structure using the field names:

```
JsonObject root = element.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray array = root.getAsJsonArray("results");
```

By accessing the JSON structure you can get to whatever you want.